# HTML form to python server

Tags: python, html, api, server

i Have python server with flask running on it

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def main():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__  == ("__main__"):
    app.run(debug = True, host = "0.0.0.0", port =80)
```

this is index.html there is simple form and send button

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>whatl0ol</title>




  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">



</head>

<body>

  <div class="login">
  <div class="heading">
    <h2></h2>
    <form action="#">

      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
          </div>



        <button type="submit" class="float">check</button>
       </form>
        </div>
 </div>



</body>

</html>
```

i need solution  to when user sends from index page, take it from python send to API.

need advices about site bandwith also.

thanks

Comment: i dont know why i get - -es

Comment: are you using any framework ? or just custom python make sure you have correct permission on css folder readable by web-server?

Comment: im using python flask server route to /

Comment: used chmod -R 777

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have css files at this path

```
/your-project/static/css/style.css
```

also change your css in template to load it from static folder

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" />
```

Comment: @whatlOol you said in comment below on next answer that there is template folder in which you have "css/style.css" please move it to /root/static/

Comment: @whatlOol i just tried to hit http://178.128.203.72/static/css/style.css and it was showing css to me as per my answer this should work if you have done it correctly.